# Why are the Tor button and Tor launcher addons no longer visible in the about:addons page?

Tags: add-on, tor-button

I used to use the Tor browser many years ago, but I uninstalled and hadn't used it until today. When I checked the browser again, I was surprised to find no Torbutton or TorLauncher addons in `about:addons`. What happened? Why were they removed? Here is what the `about:addons` page used to look like:

[image]

Comment: These projects still exist, but they're built directly into Tor Browser now and are no longer extensions.

Comment: @Steve, thank you for explaining this, but why did the Tor project do this? What was the reason for this change?

Comment: I'm not sure, my guess is that there's no reason for them to keep it separate, and that it makes maintenance/development easier to build them together.